# functional composition within a Datomic query

Tags: validation, clojure, datomic, database-security

I am passing an actual symbol for a function as an argument to a Datomic query. Is this discouraged? Would you suggest generating the whole query dynamically instead (example would help)?

```
(d/q '[:find ?effect-o
       :in $ % ?pred-fn
       :where
       [_ :my/effect_o ?effect-o]
       [(db.utilities/binary_sentiment ?pred-fn ?effect-o)]]
     (get_db) ALL_RULES pred_fn)

(defn binary_sentiment [binary_pred_fn score]
  (binary_pred_fn score)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice trick. The semantics are well-defined, so you should have no problems with this.

Comment: I was worried that query arguments would be restricted to Datomic types for security reasons.

Comment: This is likely true with clients, but not with peers.  Peers are "inside" the database and trusted.

Comment: Are you saying that any input, from a webpage for example, should have been validated already? Since peers are "inside" the database, the queries and db functions are analogous to a stored procedure in the SQL world. This means that it is the responsibility of the peer to validate inputs to the db.

Comment: I've also made this into a separate question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154627/security-in-functional-programming